# Reading perl script error: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to read perl script from a perl file but I am getting CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

The code below is what I am having now.

```
public static void Extract(){
    Process process;

    try
    {
        String testFile = "C:\\Users\\luenwong\\Desktop\\hello_world.pl";
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(testFile);
        process.getOutputStream();

        process.waitFor();
        if(process.exitValue() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Command Successful");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String answer = sb.toString();

            System.out.println("Answer "+ answer);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Command Failure");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.toString());
    }
}
```

I have found some of the people with the same error as mine but they are trying to read bash file but not perl script. So that I was wondering will it be the same error as them. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Perl installed?  Windows does not ship with Perl installed, which means that you'll need to compile Perl from the source code or install a Perl distribution for Windows.  Some popular Perl distributions for Windows are [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/), ActiveState's [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) and [Citrus Perl](http://citrusperl.com/).

Personally, I have gotten into the habit of typing "perl script.pl" instead of just "script.pl" to run my Perl scripts in Windows.  The second method, which appears to be what you're trying to use, relies on having setup a file association in Windows so that the OS knows to use perl.exe for all *.pl files.  To find out if you have a file association set up for .pl files, you can open a command prompt and type 'assoc .pl'.  If you don't see a file association has been setup for *.pl files, then you need to modify your code be calling "perl C:\Users\luenwong\Desktop\hello_world.pl" instead of "C:\Users\luenwong\Desktop\hello_world.pl".  Or you can try to fix the file association.  Doing a quick search, I found this set of [instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs) for doing this on Windows 7.  The steps might be slightly different for other Windows OS.

I won't be able to help debug issues in your Java code, but if your code is doing what I think it's doing, it would appear that you don't have Perl installed or you don't have a file association set up for *.pl files.  So verifying that Perl is installed and checking the file associations would be my first steps in debugging the Perl side of things.